# Is it possible to connect one electrical device to two electric sockets?

Tags: circuit-design

Let's assume I have an electrical device like a tv set connected to a power outlet and it is running. I want to switch the electrical connection to another socket without interrupting the tv show I am watching.

Could I clamp on a second power cord to the wires in the first one, plug the second cord into the second socket, and then pull the first plug?

**What happens, if anything, if a device is plugged into two electical outlet sockets at the same time?**

Does it make a difference for AC versus DC? Do the phases of AC have to be in tune? Does the voltage change (e.g. add up)?

Comment: The pins of the second plug will be "live" and dangerous.

Comment: @SteveG Of course! I don't mean to imply that what I describe is something that should be done. I only want to understand. I'm doing research for a story I am writing.

Comment: What problem is the action hero trying to solve? We could help you with the plot!

Comment: If the outlets are connected to the same fuse group it should be possible. The outlets will be connected by the buildings internal wiring. I would not recommend doing it in real life. As @SteveG wrote the pins of the second wire will be dangerous to touch.

Comment: If the sockets are on a different phase you will (hopefully) blow some fuses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best case, a loop. Worst case, short circuit.

---

The simple way is with a suicide/widowmaker cable.

The other way is with a [hotplug field kit.](https://www.cru-inc.com/products/wiebetech/hotplug_field_kit_product/) Often used by forensic teams to confiscate computers and servers without turning them off. Which is a really unique bit of kit.

The correct way is the get a [UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply) for the TV and just swap the UPS plug.

Answer (score 0):

It’s one of those ‘just because you can, doesn’t mean you should’ things.

File it under ‘Darwin Award Candidate’, cross referenced to ‘Hold My Beer and Watch This’.

If - and this is a very big If - you had the hot/neutral phases right, and you were connecting to the *same* hot phase, it would be possible to switch over using this method. After all, you are effectively wiring two identical wires in parallel.

If you get it wrong? Best case scenario is you pop a breaker. Worst case you fry your cord, start a fire or some other calamity.

Makes me think of this:
[image]

Is it too much to ask to get a multi-room DVR instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this with sockets connected to the same power lines and you connect live to live and neutral to neutral then it is nothing which can theoretically misbehave. But if you flipped the wires, a good short circuit awaits for you.